Disable UDP/IPv4 checksum validation for incoming packets in Linux
I am writing my UDP (on IPv4) server application in C on my Linux machine (Debian based) and I wish to disable checksum validation for ANY UDP segment that arrives to the server.
If needed, I can also configure the kernel when I build it and/or at run-time.
I saw the following answers/question/posts, but could NOT get an answer though:
this answer refers to outgoing UDP segments, and also this that does not have an answer - but anyhow refers to outgoing.
So the next thing I did is to look into how the SO_NO_CHECK is used. This value is used when the C program uses the setsockopt system call which eventually arrives to the sk_setsockopt in the Linux kernel, to set this value for the respective struct sock object.
When you "grep" for the SO_NO_CHECK (like here) in the Linux kernel source code, it is indeed again seems to effect only the Tx UDP segments checksum calculation (i.e. - disable it only for outgoing UDP segments).
The answer in this link does the same usage in the setsockopt system call and indicates that it DOES effect the Rx checksum (i.e. - disable it for incoming UDP segments) - but again, I do not understand how/why?
From "deep-diving" into the struct sock in the Linux kernel, it seems that the field sk_no_check_rx is set by default to 1 - i.e. - disable checksum calculation for incoming packets - if so, then why does the user need to explictly use the setsockopt in the first place as in the post with the answer above?
I am a little confused here, any clrafication about that would be appriciated.

Why do you want to disable the checksum? What problem is that supposed to solve? Are you using raw packets instead of the standard UDP implementation already in Linux? Why? What problem is that supposed to solve?

If the checksum is 0, then there is no validation for IPv4, otherwise it is required to validate the checksum. IPv6 requires UDP checksum validation.

@Someprogrammerdude OP is under the impression that verifying the integrity of the incoming UDP packets incurs a significant cost in CPU cycles, and therefore disabling the checksumming will allow the computer to operate more efficiently.  I suspect that he's going to find out that disabling the checksumming has no measurable effect on performance, but I could be wrong.

Checksum creation/validation is often offloaded to the NIC.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

@Someprogrammerdude - I am using the standard Linux UDP sockets with the assumption (in my case) that the UDP segments will arrive with no errors - so I do not wish to spend time on validating the checksum.

@JeremyFriesner - Yes, that is exactly what I wish to test (and maybe indeed there won't be performance effect), but I first need to test incoming UDP segments that are not being checksum-validated, and how to disable this validation I do not understand how...

@RonMaupin - thanks for the comment, and indeed I only deal with UDP segments on top of Ipv4.
